# Re-structured object first line to be name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to restructure my object into something like this.

i have an object like this

```
{
    {
        id
        name
        description
    },
    {
        22,
        test,
        lorem
    }
}
```

How can I transform it into like this.
    {
       {
           id: 22,
           name: 'test',
           description: 'lorem'
       }
    }

I really don't have an idea guys thanks.

Comment: That object is invalid - there are no values.

Comment: What you have doesn't look like valid JSON object

Comment: @dark_ruby [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you have an array of arrays and want an array of objects.

You separate keys and values and map values for new objects.

```js
var array = [['id','name','description'], [22,'test','lorem'], [34,'test 2','Ipsum'], [35,'asmet','Dolor']],
    [keys, ...values] = array,
    result = values.map(v => Object.assign(...keys.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: v[i] }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. But i have a question.What does this means
[keys, values] = array,

Comment: I really appreciate your help @Nina Scholz. Thank you :) 

How can I make it. it will also restructured the other index. right now it only restructured the 2nd index and not the rest.

Comment: please add valid data. what means *other* index, what is the *2nd* index and what goes wrong?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/4qd5a2hP

The [22,'test','lorem'] will be converted but the other will not be process

Comment: Thank you @NinaScholzs . I just change the pop into shift. :)